# Vignette in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures, vignette

I want to create a vignette effect in cocos2d. I'm not really sure how I could go about doing this. I thought about just using an image, but a high resolution, fullscreen image (this is for iPad) would take up a lot of memory. Next, I thought about using CCRenderTexture. I've never used it before, but I'm currently looking into it. What advice do you have toward accomplishing this?

I want something similar to this (notice the black near the corners and edges of the image)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you some examples (images) showing what you want achieve?

Comment: I just want some dark shading in the corners of the screen to add... ambience I guess. I've added an image for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could find or write a pixel shader to do it, but I've no experience to advise you there.  Googling *vignetting pixel shader* yields a few samples that may give you a starting point.

Alternately, the image required to do a vignette effect for 2048 x 1536 would not take up so much memory that I would dismiss it out of hand.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, researching now.